# awk paragraph with string and the following paragraph in pgn chess games

Tags: linux, awk, regular-expression, search

How can I get a paragraph with the string and the following paragraph with awk?

The file looks like this:

```
[Event "Chess game"]
[Date "2021.01.08"]
[White "Player A"]
[Black "Player B"]
[Result "0-1"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Bc5 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Nf6
7. Nxe5 Nxe5 8. d4 Ba7 9. dxe5 Ng8 10. Qd5 0-1

[Event "Chess game"]
[Date "2021.01.08"]
[White "Player B"]
[Black "Player C"]
[Result "0-1"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Bc5 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Nf6
7. Nxe5 Nxe5 8. d4 Ba7 9. dxe5 Ng8 10. Qd5 0-1

[Event "Chess game"]
[Date "2021.01.08"]
[White "Player C"]
[Black "Player A"]
[Result "0-1"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Bc5 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Nf6
7. Nxe5 Nxe5 8. d4 Ba7 9. dxe5 Ng8 10. Qd5 0-1
```

This command returns the paragraphs I want:

```
> awk '/Player A/' RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" file.pgn
```

How can I add the following paragraph with the moves of the games?

Like this:

```
[Event "Chess game"]
[Date "2021.01.08"]
[White "Player A"]
[Black "Player B"]
[Result "0-1"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Bc5 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Nf6
7. Nxe5 Nxe5 8. d4 Ba7 9. dxe5 Ng8 10. Qd5 0-1

[Event "Chess game"]
[Date "2021.01.08"]
[White "Player C"]
[Black "Player A"]
[Result "0-1"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Bc5 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Nf6
7. Nxe5 Nxe5 8. d4 Ba7 9. dxe5 Ng8 10. Qd5 0-1
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you desire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/"Player A"/{c=2} c&&c--' file
[Event "Chess game"]
[Date "2021.01.08"]
[White "Player A"]
[Black "Player B"]
[Result "0-1"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Bc5 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Nf6
7. Nxe5 Nxe5 8. d4 Ba7 9. dxe5 Ng8 10. Qd5 0-1

[Event "Chess game"]
[Date "2021.01.08"]
[White "Player C"]
[Black "Player A"]
[Result "0-1"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Bc5 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Nf6
7. Nxe5 Nxe5 8. d4 Ba7 9. dxe5 Ng8 10. Qd5 0-1
```

See [printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105) for details on how that and related idioms work.

I made the regexp to test for `Player A` from your question more robust and I used `RS=<null string>` instead of `RS='\n\n'` so it'll work in any awk, not just gawk.

Answer (score 2):

**awk** in `paragraph` mode

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '
  /"Player A"/ { var=NR+1;print }
  var==NR
' file
```

---

**perl** in `paragraph` mode (**-00**)

```
perl -00 -ne '
  print s/\z/<>/re
    if /"Player A"/ && !eof;
' file
```

---

**sed** collect chunks of non empty lines in the hold space. And from there once the target para is identified print till the nearest empty line (=> print next record)

```
sed -e '
  /./,/^$/!d
  H;/./d;x;s///
  /"Player A"/!d
  :n;n;/^$/!bn
' file
```

---

**Results:**

```
[Event "Chess game"]
[Date "2021.01.08"]
[White "Player A"]
[Black "Player B"]
[Result "0-1"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Bc5 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Nf6
7. Nxe5 Nxe5 8. d4 Ba7 9. dxe5 Ng8 10. Qd5 0-1

[Event "Chess game"]
[Date "2021.01.08"]
[White "Player C"]
[Black "Player A"]
[Result "0-1"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Bc5 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Nf6
7. Nxe5 Nxe5 8. d4 Ba7 9. dxe5 Ng8 10. Qd5 0-1
```